# Why is Cypress not finding my H1 element?

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I have some end to end tests targeting a website, implemented in Javascript using [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/) v3.2.0. One of my test steps is implemented like so:

```
cy.get('h1#feed_header_id').contains('אביזרי');  //('אביזרי' is in Hebrew)
```

When I run the test in the Cypress GUI, it fails on the CONTAINS step. But when I click on the `CONTAINS` step in the log, the snapshot clearly shows the `H1` element with the text "אביזרי" in it.

Screenshot:
[image]

Please note: The element is: `<h1 id="feed_header_id">אביזרי רכב</h1>` and is the only element with this id in the page.

Why does Cypress fail to find the text in the element when the element and the text are clearly visible?

Comment: Maybe the HTML element contains only HTML entities of the characters and not the characters itself?

Comment: We can't say without seeing the exact markup for the `h1` including the exact text within it (as text, not an image), copied and pasted. (I assume the `contains` call above is copied-and-pasted, not retyped. If not, copy-and-paste it.)

Comment: Some thoughts (keeping in mind you are **much** more familiar with the vagaries of combining LTR and RTL in code than I am! :-) ): 1. Could one of them have an RTL mark and the other not? 2. Is there more than one Unicode sequence that encodes that Hebrew text? If so, you probably want to normalize both the text in the `h1` and the search text (for instance, to Normalized Form C). I use French as an example: `"Français" === "Français"` is false because one of those uses U+00E7 for `ç` and the other uses U+0063 and U+0327, but `"Français".normalize() === "Français".normalize()` is true.

Comment: T.J.Crowder makes some fine points. I can't repro the problem on my end, using the HTML and assertion you supplied, verbatim.

Comment: Thanks @GhostGambler, tj-crowder, dwelle. I've added the markup to the question. No use of HTML entites on my end. I too am unable to create a simple repro. I can add that this is not deterministic. Runs as part of large set of tests and sometimes happens, other times not. :/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the alternate 'contains' command,

```js
cy.contains('#feed_header_id', 'אביזרי');
```

The reason is that `cy.get(...).contains(...)` does not wait for async ***content***.

The `get()` part has automatic retry, but the id selector is hard-coded in your html, so `get()` succeeds immediately (before the xhr returns it's value), then the element is tested for content (which is initially empty).

The alternate syntax above applies auto-retry to both the selector and the content.

Here is a quick test I used to ensure it is not due to RTL language features.

**Spec - contains-rtl.js**

```js
describe('contains', () => {
  it('waits for content', () => {
    cy.visit('app/hebrew-calendar.html').then(x => console.log('x', x))
    // cy.get('h1#feed_header_id').contains('כ״ט בְּאִיָּר תשע״א');
    cy.contains('h1#feed_header_id', 'כ״ט בְּאִיָּר תשע״א');
  })
})
```

**Sample page - hebrew-calendar.html**

```html
<h1 id="feed_header_id"></h1>

<script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.hebcal.com/converter/?cfg=json&gy=2011&gm=6&gd=2&g2h=1', true);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    const hebrewDate = JSON.parse(xhr.response).hebrew;
    const el = document.querySelector('h1#feed_header_id');
    el.textContent = hebrewDate;
  };

  xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have multiple elements with the same text.
Try `cy.get('#feed_header_id').find('h1').contains('אביזרי');`

Comment: Thanks @payel-roy-burman . In my case the element is simply `<h1 id="feed_header_id">אביזרי רכב</h1>` so only one instance of the element and the text. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the blame is in the testing tool.

Some test tools have problems with RTL languages and they reverse the order of the letters. Worse if there is Latin or digit or punctuation in the string it convert the string as well.

I suggest trying:

```
cy.get('h1#feed_header_id').contains('ירזיבא');
```